# Can I have too many mods?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, steam, mods

I found a lot of mods that make thinks lighter, and add mark and recall, and a basement I like. They are all on Steam, and what I want to know is if I can have too many? Will they all work together? Or should I just leave them alone?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The number of mods Skyrim can handle seems to be limited by an unsigned byte, meaning slightly less than ~256 mods.  ([this account](http://www.bethblog.com/2012/02/28/skyrim-1-4-27-released-on-steam/comment-page-1/#comment-238867) says 252 accounting for Skyrim.esm, the Update.esm, and the Saved game)

If you need more, some tools such as [Wrye Bash](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/downloads/file.php?id=1840) can combine mods together, but this means you will need to manage these mods outside of Steam Workshop ([Nexus Mod Manager](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/content/modmanager/) is a good option).

Previously there was a [50 mod subscription bug](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?p=29073259) with Steam Workshop, but it looks like [Update 1.4.27](http://www.bethblog.com/2012/02/28/skyrim-1-4-27-released-on-steam/) fixed that issue.

Comment: That's a Steam Workshop issue though.

Comment: The question specified mods available on Steam.  Is there another way to use mods available through Steam without using Steam Workshop?

Comment: you're right, I missed that bit. Still, most good mods will be available from an alternative location, such as the Skyrim Nexus.

Comment: Edited to include a bit of info about Skyrim Nexus.

Comment: Also, [Wrye Bash](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/downloads/file.php?id=1840) can combine .esp files to help you get under the hard 255 mods limit.

Answer (score 6):

Oblivion and Morrowind where limited to 255 mods, so we could assume that Skyrim have the same limit too. That said, 255 is still a rather high number, so unless you're grabbing every mod you find, you should be fine.

As for compatibility, it really depends on the mod and the load order. Some mod may work without problem, others only in a certain order, and some others just won't work together. It is a case-by-case problem, so you should carefully read the README of the mods, and you should try using tools such as [Wrye Bash](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/downloads/file.php?id=1840) and [BOSS](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/downloads/file.php?id=6) to keep them organized.

Answer (score 1):

it depends on the mods. Remember, mods are made by random people. If you're lucky, they do enough quality control on their own works, but most probably they don't care about other mods (unless they're really really famous).
So recommendation, just use what you really need.

Answer (score 1):

Only subscribe to dynamic and constantly updating mods. For example, the dovahkiin hideout or midas magic, which keeps updating.

But for something like the paarthurnax fix or perfected weapon mods (that require no more attention), you unsubscribe but keep the data files so they remain in your skyrim but are no longer 'subscribed' as such.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, there's no such thing as 'too many' *per se*.

However, mods can conflict with each other, and some do expand the demands the game places on your system (I.E. texture packs).

Other than known or obvious conflicts though (you **DO** read the README, right?), all you can do is try them and see. If you have issues after installing a bunch of mods, disable them one by one (or the reverse) - its really the only reliable way to troubleshoot.

Answer (score -1):

I am using NMM and i can't run more than 255 mods, when i select 256th a msg appears that you can not use more mods.
So i am currently running 255 mods with NMM..

But you can run as many mods as you want which don't need install (means the mods which don't have esp or esm files like the textures, sounds, meshes like stuff)